# jqGrid - loading values from JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have a `jqGrid` working OK using the `local` datatype, but I now want the values to be loaded via `json` but having trouble changing it.

This is my `jqGrid` code

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        url: "/controller/getItems?id=2",
        width: 1405,
        colNames: ['id', 'surname'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', index: 'id', editable: false, hidden: false, hidedlg: true },
            { name: 'surname', index: 'surname', editable: true }
        ],
        onSelectRow: function (id, status, e) {

        ...
    },
    editurl: url,

     ...
```

So the method to get the JSON is sucessfully fired.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult getItems(string id)
    {

        List<model> items = method.getItems(id);
        string jsonText = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(items);
        return Json(jsonText, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

*The column names in the `JSON` do match the `colModel` names*

Example of the `json` being returned  - what the object `jsonText` above contains

```
[{"id":434,"surname":"Woods"},
{"id":435,"surname":"Adams"}]
```

Is there anything I have done wrong or am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a typo in 3rd line of JS? You're missing quotes aroud URL.

Comment: Thanks for the spot, it was just a typo in the question. will change

Comment: Can you please post the response along with response headers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the error in in using of `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize`. You need just return `Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. Additionally you can remove the column `id` from the `colModel`. The `id` value will be still read and assigned as the value of `id` attribute of the rows (`id` of `<tr>` elements of the grid) known as rowid. You should add `loadonce: true` option to the grid because you don't implemented paging of data on the server side and to add `gridview: true` (if you not already use it) to have better performance and `autoencode: true` to interpret input data as texts instead of HTML fragments.

**UPDATED**: In case of usage old version of jqGrid one have to include `jsonReader` parameter which corresponds the format of input data:

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) { return obj; }
}
```

One should still use `loadonce: true` option additionally.

Comment: Hi @oleg, thank for the info. However, doing the changes you stated, I still get no data loaded into the grid. I am not using `jsonReader` could this be a problem?

Comment: @user3428422: Which version of jqGrid you use? If you use the current version then you don't need any `jsonReader`. I recommend you to use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press F12 to start) or Chrome or Firefox to examine HTTP traffic. You will see what will be send to the server and what come back to web browser. After that it will be clear where there are the problem.

Comment: Hi @oleg - version is jqGrid  4.4.4 - 2008. When I use firebug the response `json` is what I posted above, also there are no syntax or servers errors

Comment: @user3428422: Do you like to have a lot of old problems? Why you use retro versions of jqGrid? Only if you **really can't update to new jqGrid** you can just add `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: function (obj) { return obj; } }`. It sould solve the problem. See [the part of the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function) which I wrote many years ago. In any way I would recommend you to examine HTTP traffic to be sure that the data returned from the server are correct.

Comment: Thanks @oleg, its because someone wrote this code years ago (and I got it back to fix bugs and do enhancements) however I can't refactor all of it as its legacy code and other developers know the structure and current libraries, so as you can see, I am trying to do tweaks - which if any other developer is reading this means you can (normally) get trouble like this so its not wise!

Comment: @user3428422: Is the usage of `jsonReader` from my previous comment solved the problem?

Comment: yes thanks! I did use that before resulting to SO but I still had the `serialiser` in which you pointed out, so I think the answer was taking the `serialiser out` and using `jsonReader`... you should really be on the SO payroll!

Comment: @user3428422: I'm glad that I could help you. You are welcome!